# Unable to access local SQL Server Express

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-express

I have an ASP.NET (MVC 5) web application that works fine locally, but when I publish it to the IIS Server, I get the following error page when I hit the Controller that accesses the database.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.)

This is what my `web.config` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="DefaultConnection" 
          connectionString="Data Source=WIN-ALUKOTV9R\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Staging;Persist Security=True;User Id=MyWebUser;Password=password" 
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

This is on a staging server so I installed Visual Studio directly on that VM (which has IIS and SQL Server 2014 Express installed). I can added this database to the Visual Studio Server Explorer pane just fine using the same Connection String. But for some reason it isn't working in IIS.

One more thing worth mentioning, a long time ago there used to be a server named NOSS, so at one point I had a connection string pointing to NOSS. But now when I look at the web.config that gets generated in the deployment folder I see the old connection string, and two other random connection strings. I don't know where they came from, so I end up manually deleting those useless ones. The one I leave is the `DefaultConnection` one.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Staging;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=MyWebUser;Password=password" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Logistix.Repository.Repositories.LogistixContext" 
         connectionString="Data Source=NOSS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Logistix;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=MyWebUser;Password=password" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Logistix.Web.LogistixDataContext" 
         connectionString="Logistix.Web.LogistixDataContext_ConnectionString" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Logistix.Web.Models.LogistixWebContext" 
         connectionString="Logistix.Web.Models.LogistixWebContext_ConnectionString" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: are you sure the computer name is valid in your connectionstring to connect to the database? unlikely I think... generally if the DB is installed on the same machine as the website, you would do (local)\SQLExpress or .\SQLExpress

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work. In my web.config that gets generated after deployment, I have three additional elements under the connectionStrings xml element which aren't in my web.config under the source tree (in VS). Is that normal?

Comment: Try doing localhost\SQLExpress in the connection string. Because AFAIK SQLExpress is not supported over the network and not meant for production. The app and the database should always be on the same server.